# How to compare current array element to next array element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have color templates that users can choose between and also change the individual colors if they want. I have two arrays: one with all the templates, and each template containing a color palette of 8 total colors and a string of the template name. Most of my templates have white backgrounds, so I don't want the user to have to click 12 times or however many it takes to get to another index where the background color is different. My idea was to use a "for" statement to check the next element in my array, and compare it to the current element to see if they are identical. If the elements are identical, then I increment the array and the "for" statement checks again, effectively skipping any duplicate indices until a new value is found.

To do this, I use a "for" statement like this:

`( ; array[index][colorSlot] == array[index+1][colorSlot]; index++)`

This works perfectly until I get to the last array index and it looks for the next index which obviously doesn't exist, thus completely breaking my function. Is there a way to prevent it from looking into an array index that doesn't exist? Should I use something other than a "for" statement?

Comment: Go up to array.length -2 in the for loop. Also why do you have a loopcount and use index.

Comment: @arundeepchohan, how do I do that?

Comment: Your for-statement looks some confusing: initialize of `loopcount`,condition with `array` and increment of `index`. Are you sure this is the right way?

Comment: @Sascha, sorry, I guess I don't need any initialization. Edited it out.

Answer (score 0):

You'd prob want to go up to the second last array index and skip all repeats.

```
for(let index=0; index<array.length-2; index++)
{
    if[index][colorSlot] != array[index+1][colorSlot]
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with a while loop it's better choice than a for-loop in your case.

```js
let index = 0;
while (index < array.length -2 && array[index][colorSlot] != array[index+1][colorSlot] ) {
    ...
    index++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.

In my for loop, I check for two conditions: FIRST, I check to see if `[index+1]!=array.length` and THEN I check to see if the current array value is equal to the next (as written above). If checking the next value of the index would cause it to search an index that does not exist, it exits the for statement and resets my index.